# Matlab - adapt xlim and ylim to remove white margin with surfc

Tags: matlab, surface

I get an issue about the plot of 2d map of a surface with temperature (represented by color). The solution that I plot here is symmetric.

array `x` represents the array containing the temperature on (`sizex`,`sizey`) map size. In my code, `sizex = 256` and `sizey = 96`.

I plot with the following code snippet :

```
surfc(x);
shading interp;
view([0,0,1]);
hc=colorbar;
set(hc,'position',[0.932 0.3 0.02 0.6]);
caxis([-10 10]);
xlabel('x domain');
ylabel('y domain');
zlabel('temperature');
xlim([0 sizex+2]);
ylim([0 sizey+2]);
```

and I get the following figure :

[image: with margin equal to +2]

As you can see in the script, I added "2" to `sizex` and `sizey` to fill a white exterior margin.

If I don't add these values, i.e doing :

```
xlim([0 sizex]);
ylim([0 sizey]);
```

Then, I get the following figure :

[image: without adding 2 to xlim ylim]

And you can notice that parts of solution on right and upper sides are not displayed (rather hidden).

You can also see that even on the first figure above (like also for the second figure) (with adding "2" to `xlim` and `ylim`), it remains a slight white margin on bottom and I don't know how to remove it.

More precisely, I would like to fit exactly the dimensions of plot with dimensions of the grid data, i.e having temperature over `256x96` size without having margins.

Comment: Could you upload the data in x?

Comment: -@Max you can see data on https://pastebin.com/fTuhm8aH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you defined `sizex` and `sizey` wrong. I copied your data from pastebin and `size(x)` yields `[258,98]` and not `[256,96]`.
Now the other problem that you have is the following: You feed a 2D-Matrix `x` to `surfc`. Now what the command does, is putting the value `x(1,1)` at position `(1,1)` in the plot. If you don't want these "white borders" you need to put the value at position `(0,0)` instead. You can achieve that by feeding three matrices `X`,`Y`,`Z` to the `surfc`-command. You can genereate the matrices as follows:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(0:size(x,2)-1,0:size(x,1)-1);
Z=x;
surfc(X,Y,Z);
% From here on your regular code starts
shading interp;
view([0,0,1]);
hc=colorbar;
set(hc,'position',[0.932 0.3 0.02 0.6]);
caxis([-10 10]);
xlabel('x domain');
ylabel('y domain');
zlabel('temperature');
```

You should not need to define the limits of the plot now. In case you still need to, use this:

```
xlim([0,size(x,2)-1]);
ylim([0,size(x,1)-1]);
```